# Django store information in one variable

Tags: python, django, session

I have different pages with items, each item has its own price which I would like to store in one variable and then send all of them to paypal payment form.
So question is,how can I store information about price from different pages? I tried sessions but nothing happens.

```
        <article>
 {% block content %}
        <span>Kuriame mieste registruojiesi</span>
        <select>
            {% for item in upsell.skaidyti_miestus %}
                <option value="{{item}}">{{ item }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
     {%if upsell.prideti_upsell_nr_2_taip%} 
        <button onclick="location.href='/upselliai/{{upsell.upsell_nr2_taip.id}}/pirkti/'">Taip, pridÄ—ti prie bendros sumos</button>
     <!-- {#prideti kaina paimti ID} -->
        {% else %}
     <button onclick="location.href='/pirkejas/apmoketi'">Taip, pridÄ—ti prie bendros sumos</button>
     {%endif%}
     {%if upsell.prideti_upsell_nr_2_ne%}   
        <a href="/upselliai/{{upsell.upsell_nr2_ne.id}}/pirkti/">{{ upsell.atsisakymo_tekstas }}</a>
        <!-- {#prideti kaina paimti ID} -->
     {% else %}
     <a href="/pirkejas/apmoketi">{{ upsell.atsisakymo_tekstas }}</a>
     {%endif%}
{% endblock %}
    </article>
```

my views.py

```
def pirkti_upsell(request, upsellis_id = 1):

#if 'pirkejas_id' in request.session:
session_pirkejas_id = request.session['pirkejas_id']
Upsellis.objects.get(id = upsellis_id).sum(session_pirkejas_id)

return render_to_response("upsell_template.html", {"upsell": Upsellis.objects.get(id = upsellis_id)})
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "nothing happens". You are not singing the result of the aggregate call to a variable or sending it to the template context, so it is being ignored.

Comment: Probably you misunderstand me. I want update information about price in database not in template.

Comment: Well, you're right that I don't understand you, because you haven't given enough information about what you want to do and what's wrong with the code you have.